# API Gateway Is it possible to set a custom domain name for API Gateway and integrate it with a new CloudFront?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

My API endpoint type is edge-optimized. I have a custom domain name API like `www.example.com` and I want to add a new CloudFront which to block specific countries request in front of my API Gateway.

How to add a new CloudFront in front of my API Gateway and use the same domain name (www.example.com)? I am confused. Is it possible to do that?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to do that. You should follow the following steps.

- Create a origin for your API Gateway inside your CloudFront
  distribution. There you should enter the endpoint of your API Gateway
  for the origin domain name.
- Then you need to create a behavior inside
  the CloudFront distribution which forwards requests that match a
  specific path pattern to your API Gateway. (Make sure that you put
  the Minimum TTL to as 0, since we don't want to cache the the API
  requests)

See the following documentation for further reference.

[Custom origins](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_Origin.html)

[Cache behaviors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior)

Comment: If I create a distribution by using the API invoke url such as https://xxxx.execute-api.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/test. I will get a domain name like "xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net". How could I associate it to my exist custom domain name? The custom domain name already add a A record (Target Domain Name
xxxxx.cloudfront.net) in Route 53.

Comment: Yes, of course. as I mentioned earlier, once you create path pattern in caching behavior such as www.yourdomain.com/ap ,i all of your requests to that path pattern will be forwarded to your API gateway invoke URL.

Comment: @IggyGreen before you can associate the hostname with the CloudFront distribution, that hostname will need to be decoupled from your API Gateway deployment.  You can't make this change without a brief service interruption.

Comment: You will also need to disable forwarding for the Host header